# WebScraping through multiple sites with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium in a project that consists of opening a range of websites, that contains pretty much the same structure, collecting data in each site and storing it.

The problem I ran into is that some of the sites I wan't to access are unavailable, and when the program get to one of those it just stops.

What I want it to do, is to skip those and follow on with the next iterations, but so far my tries have been obsolete... In my latest try I used the method is_displayed(), but apparently it will only tell me if an element is visible or not, instead of telling me if it's present or not.

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-2"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/strong').is_displayed():
```

The example above doesn't work, because the driver needs to find the element before telling me if it visible or not, but the element is simply not there.

Have any of you dealt with something similar?

[How one of the sites looks like normally](https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/xpml11)

[How it looks like when it is unavailable](https://statusinvest.com.br/fundos-imobiliarios/afri11)

Comment: avoid that xpaths with [1] [x] and use element's attributes

Comment: @Wonka is there any particular reason to why I should avoid it? I copied the xpath from the elements terminal, what other way would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Selenium expected conditions waiting for element presence.
I'm just giving an example below.
I have defined the timeout for 5 seconds here, but you can use any timeout value.
Also, your element locator looks bad.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element_xpath_locator = '//*[@id="main-2"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/strong'
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element_xpath_locator)))
```

Comment: Hadn't had the time yet to think how I'm going to implement this to my code, but will soon check it. Thanks! Also, what's wrong with my element locator?

Comment: The locator is too long and complex. I'm quite sure you took it from dev tools automatically generated while correct locators never looking like this. You should learn how to do that.

Comment: So, did you try this? Did it resolve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mark it as a solution. It did work, but not exactly as I was expecting. I've set WebDriverWait(browser, 2) inside a try and added an except with TimeoutException. What surprised me though is that even after 2 or more seconds in the exceptional page the code would still be looking for the element, and would only go to the except after some more time.

Comment: Well, first of all I would suggest setting the explicit wait timeout to some longer period. Normally we use 20 or 30 seconds since with explicit wait if element normally there this will not make your test run longer. Immediately when Selenium detects the expected condition the flow will continue. But by setting too short timeout there you may cause tests fail on timeout if page still not loaded due to slow internet etc.

Comment: I can't know why your runs taking more time than the set explicit waits, need to see it's debugging, but I can guess it is because of driver.get() command at the beginning. Since driver.get() command passes the control to the next code line only after the page is loaded. Not completely, but still some kind of.

Comment: I understand, thank you! Is there a method that passes the control to next line before loading? It doesn't sound like a good idea, but in this case it looks like it would be useful.

Comment: Maybe with JavaScript, but not with Java, C# or Python AFAIK

Comment: I see, well thank you anyway, you have been really helpful!

Comment: It's my pleasure :)